# Draw div with scrollHeight

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to draw a div with height of entire document. An id named "background" should have the height equal to the content. I am trying to get the result by getting the scrollHeight. I already know the height from the code below but I don't know how to put the value into css. Thank you in advance for any help!

```js
document.getElementById("background").text = ("scrollHeight : " + $(".demo").prop("scrollHeight"));
```

```css
.content {
  background: #eee;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
}

#background {
  width: 200px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="background"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want the `div` `height` to increase as we scroll!

Comment: I need #background height 100% of the entire page (body)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```js
document.querySelector('#background').setAttribute('style','height:'+ window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.content')).getPropertyValue('height'));
```

```css
.content {
  background: #eee;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
}

#background {
  width: 200px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /*height: 200px;*/
}
```

```html
<div id="background"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To have the same height for the background every time you change the content `height` it has to be a child of content.

And for the background set the height to `inherit`

```css
.content {
  background: #eee;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
}

#background {
  width: 200px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div id="background"></div>
</div>
```

Hope I could help you.

Answer (score -1):

`document.getElementById("background").style.height = <get .content height>`

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_height.asp